# Cannot REsolve Symbol error for OnClickEvent & ViewObservable when using RxAndroid

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I am getting `Cannot Resolve Symbols...` for `import rx.android.view.OnClickEvent;` and `import rx.android.view.ViewObservable` below.

What am I missing, I do have the following in my build.gradle File too: `compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'`

I am really just trying to use the code [here on Github](https://github.com/tutsplus/Android-ReactiveXIntroduction/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/hathy/rxtutorial/EventsActivity.java) to learn RxAndroid.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;

import rx.Observable;
import rx.android.view.OnClickEvent;
import rx.android.view.ViewObservable;
import rx.functions.Action1;

import com.myapp.myapp.R;


public class EventsActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.events_activity);

    Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
    Observable<OnClickEvent> clicksObservable = ViewObservable.clicks(myButton);

    clicksObservable
            .skip(4)
            .subscribe(new Action1<OnClickEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void call(OnClickEvent onClickEvent) {
                    Log.d("Click Action", "Clicked!");
                }
            });
}
}
```

Screenshot showing error points:
[image]

Comment: If you look at your imports, where it says `rx.android.view` you'll notice `view` is in red. Try removing those lines then auto-importing when it asks.

Comment: That's exactly the problem, it does not auto import anything for `OnClickEvent` and `ViewObservable`

Answer (score 4):

It seems that [ViewObservable was moved](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/wiki#moved) to [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding).

For your case, in your `onCreate` method, a button a click would look like the following:

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
Observable<Void> clicksObservable = RxView.clicks(myButton);

clicksObservable
        .skip(4)
        .subscribe(new Action1<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Void v) {
                Log.d("Click Action", "Clicked!");
            }
        });
```

Make sure to add the appropriate libraries from [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding) to your project for what you need to your Gradle build file. At minimum this will be `compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.3.0'`, but you may need others depending on if and which versions of support, design, and appcompat libraries you use.